# Doctrine/Symfony: How to include EntityManager in EntityListener

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have an entity `BaseInformation`

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\EntityListeners({"AppBundle\EntityListener\BaseInformationListener"})
 * @ORM\Table(name="BaseInformation")
 */
class BaseInformation
{ ...
```

Therefore I have an `EntityListener`

```
/**
 * Class BaseInformationListener
 * @package AppBundle\EventListener
 */
class BaseInformationListener
{
    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     *
     * @param BaseInformation $baseInformation
     * @param PreUpdateEventArgs $event
     */
    public function preUpdateHandler(BaseInformation $baseInformation, PreUpdateEventArgs $event)
    {
        dump($baseInformation);
        dump($event->getEntityChangeSet());
    }
}
```

I need to save the `ChangeSet` into the database. But I have no access to an `EntityManager`. I can make a service out of it, but the listener is automatically called over the annotation in the entity. So how do I have access to the `EntityManager` to save my `ChangeSet` for example?

Comment: which version of doctrine are you using?

Comment: Overlooking the obvious perhaps? $event->getEventManager(); http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/class-Doctrine.ORM.Event.PreUpdateEventArgs.html  Be careful though, trying to use the entity manager inside of these sorts of events seldom ends well.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the listener a service and tag it as an EntityListener so you can use the dependency you need as usually:

```
services:
    base_information_listener:
        class: AppBundle\EntityListener\BaseInformationListener
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener }
```

Prior to doctrine 2.5 you need to use the annotation in the related entity also ([as described in the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineBundle/entity-listeners.html)).

Hope this help

Comment: Tried it, then I have this Exception: ORMException in ORMException.php line 38: It's a requirement to specify a Metadata Driver and pass it to Doctrine\ORM\Configuration::setMetadataDriverImpl(). Because I set <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.entity_manager"/> in the service to get teh entityManager

Comment: hi @Zwen2012 the problem is described [here on github](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/300) you can try injecting the whole container (but it is not a best practice) or solve as described in the last comment (with a release of 14 days ago)